# Program not giving the desired solution

Tags: vb.net

Objective is to write a code in only VB that will check the user Id and see if it is in the right format. The first letter should be capital, the next 3 should be lower case, and the next three should be numbers. My program is outputting "Format is not right" no matter what. Even if I type the right format:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim userID As String
    Dim a, b, c, d, e, f, g As Integer

    Console.WriteLine("Input User ID")
    userID = Console.ReadLine

    'Take Hall123 as a example of a correct format

    a = Asc(Left(userID, 1))
    'First capital letter

    b = Asc(Mid(userID, 2, 1))
    'First lower case

    c = Asc(Mid(userID, 3, 1))
    'Second lower case

    d = Asc(Mid(userID, 4, 1))
    'Third lower case

    e = Asc(Mid(userID, 5, 1))
    'd contains the first number

    f = Asc(Mid(userID, 6, 1))
    'e contains the second number

    g = Asc(Mid(userID, 7, 1))
    'f contains the third number

    'just checking
    Console.WriteLine(a)
    Console.WriteLine(b)
    Console.WriteLine(c)
    Console.WriteLine(d)
    Console.WriteLine(e)
    Console.WriteLine(f)

    If Len(userID) = 7 Then
        If a >= 65 And a <= 90 Then
            If b >= 97 And b <= 122 And c >= 97 And c <= 122 And d >= 97 And d <= 122 Then
                If e <= 57 And 48 >= e And f <= 57 And 48 >= f And g <= 57 And g >= 48 Then
                    Console.WriteLine("Format is correct")
                Else
                    Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")
                End If
            Else
                Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")
            End If

        Else
            Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")

        End If
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")
    End If

    Console.ReadKey()

End Sub
```

Am I using the Mid function function correctly? I only studied it yesterday....

Comment: Have you checked the Debug window to verify that a, b, c, d, e, f, and g are what they should be?

Comment: I am not great at regular expressions, but this seems like a good case for a regular expression. Is there a reason you are not using regular expressions? Documentation found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

`Mid` is a holdover from the pre .Net days, it is better to use `SubString` these days. You don't need to use either method to access single characters in the string. Strings can be treated as arrays of Char, so you can access (for example) the third character as `userID(2)`.

There is really no point converting characters to their ASCII equivalents and then checking those numbers. The Framework provides methods to check characters to see if they are letters, numbers, upper or lower case, etc.

You can use the following function to check for a valid userID

```
Function CheckUserId(userID As String) As Boolean
    If userID.Length <> 7 Then Return False
    If Not Char.IsUpper(userID(0)) Then Return False

    For i As Integer = 1 To 3
        If Not Char.IsLower(userID(i)) Then Return False
    Next

    For i As Integer = 4 To 6
        If Not Char.IsDigit(userID(i)) Then Return False
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

You can can the function like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Console.WriteLine("Input User ID")
    Dim userID as String = Console.ReadLine

    If CheckUserId(userID) Then 
        Console.WriteLine("Format is correct")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("Format is not correct")
    End If
End Sub
```